# How different are types X and X in structure/union?

Tags: c, casting

Consider the following code:

```
struct blah {
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct foo {
    union {
        struct {
            struct blah *b;
        };
    };
};

int main()
{
    struct foo f;
    struct blah *b;

    // Warning on below assignment
    b = &f.b;
    return 0;
}
```

Why does GCC generate an `assignment from incompatible pointer type` warning, despite both LHS and RHS being of the same type (apparently)? IOW, what changes when `struct blah` is nested inside `struct foo`?

If there's a valid caveat here, what is it?

Answer (score 3):

`b = &f.b;` tries to assign a `blah**` to `b`.  Use `b = f.b;` instead

Answer (score 1):

```
struct blah {
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct foo {
    union {
        struct {
            struct blah b;
        };
    };
};
```

You are referencing `b` which is already a pointer.